# How to not bind the property which as default value in web api return

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have many classes , methods and I need some data which as default value should not be serialized, if this should done in return of webapi i don't need all the class to change. can anyone as a idea please share.

I have done in the application start like the following code.
But it doesn't work for me. In addition, I need to remove the properties which has default value on serialization.

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
});


var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
```

Comment: Please could you give more example

Comment: We need to see your current implementation to help you, post some code. Have you tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx

Comment: Also, what does it mean "it doesn't work"? There is nothing like that in the programming. Describe how it behaves, what errors did you get, what's the expected behavior, etc.